# bootstrap blazor dialog, prompting two in the same function

Tags: modal-dialog, blazor

I have a simple dialog box ffrom bootstrapblazor

```
<div>
    @* user input *@
    @if (ShowInputField)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputField">@InputFieldLabel</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputField" @bind-value="InputFieldValue" />
        </div>
    }

    @* message *@
    @if (!ShowInputField)
    {
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Message
        </div>
    }

</div>

@implements BootstrapBlazor.Components.IResultDialog

@code {

    // whether to include input field in the dialog or just show some message
    [Parameter]
    public bool ShowInputField { get; set; } = false;

    [Parameter]
    public string InputFieldLabel { get; set; } = "";

    public string InputFieldValue { get; set; } = "";

    [Parameter]
    public string Message { get; set; } = "";

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> InputFieldValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<DialogResult> DialogClosed { get; set; }

    public async Task OnClose(DialogResult result)
    {
        if (ShowInputField == true && result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            await InputFieldValueChanged.InvokeAsync(InputFieldValue);
        }

        await DialogClosed.InvokeAsync(result);
    }
}
```

Im trying to invoke two different prompts(dialogs) in the same function that way:

```
 private async Task OpenDialogsSequentially9()
    {
        var result_1 = await DialogService.ShowModal<DialogBox>(new ResultDialogOption()
            {
                Title = "prompt1",
                Size = Size.Medium,
                Component = BootstrapDynamicComponent.CreateComponent<DialogBox>(),
                ButtonYesText = "Yes",
                ButtonNoText = "No",
                ShowCloseButton = true,
                ButtonCloseText = "Cancel",
                ComponentParamters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    [nameof(DialogBox.ShowInputField)] = true,
                    [nameof(DialogBox.InputFieldLabel)] = "enter container number: ",
                    [nameof(DialogBox.InputFieldValueChanged)] = EventCallback.Factory.Create<string>(this, OnDialogInputFieldValueChanged),
                    [nameof(DialogBox.DialogClosed)] = EventCallback.Factory.Create<DialogResult>(this, OnFirstDialogClosed)
                }
            });


        if (result_1 == DialogResult.No)
        {
            await PerformDbOperations();
        }

        //do some more stuff..

        var result_2 = await DialogService.ShowModal<DialogBox>(new ResultDialogOption()
            {
                Title = "prompt2",
                Size = Size.Medium,
                Component = BootstrapDynamicComponent.CreateComponent<DialogBox>(),
                ButtonYesText = "Yes",
                ButtonNoText = "No",
                ComponentParamters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    [nameof(DialogBox.ShowInputField)] = false,
                    [nameof(DialogBox.Message)] = "store days too high, still want to proceed?",
                    [nameof(DialogBox.DialogClosed)] = EventCallback.Factory.Create<DialogResult>(this, OnFirstDialogClosed2)
                }
            });
    }
```

OnFirstDialogClosed, OnFirstDialogClosed2 are just two simple methods that execute db insertion procedure each with its own values, and same for 'await PerformDbOperations()'

```
   private async Task OnFirstDialogClosed(DialogResult result)
    {
        SqlParameter param_sContainer = new SqlParameter("@sContainer", "test");
        SqlParameter param_sManifest = new SqlParameter("@sManifest", "test");
        SqlParameter param_sDealNumber = new SqlParameter("@sDealNumber", "test");
        SqlParameter param_FormSbTerminal = new SqlParameter("@Form_Switchboard_Terminal", "test");
        await _storedProcedureHelper.ExecuteProcedureAsync("Conv_form_frmDeliveryMain_Container_COT_Rent_4", param_sContainer, param_sManifest,
              param_sDealNumber, param_FormSbTerminal);
    }
```

The thing is, given the above, only the first dialog is shown, and only onfirstdialogclose() and PerformDbOperations() are working.

Any line that comes after (for example the prompt of second dialog),is not shown. what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I've noticed that the second prompt is being displayed for like 0.01 seconds and then is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the only problem was a rendering problem.
waiting 0.2 sec inbetween each prompt will solve the problem.